# dns2tcp Error socket.c:107 bind error

Tags: tcp, terminal, dns

When I try and set up my DNS server to use dns2tcp using `sudo dns2tcpd -F -d 3 -f ~/etc/dns2tcpdrc.conf` I get the error `Error socket.c:107 bind error`
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

something running in port 53 . to find use sudo netstat -anp | grep :53 
Then use kill PID
[just see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxpP2.png)